# Simulate a pipeline got Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I’am trying to create my first pipeline so i followed to recommendation to validate my …gitlab-ci.yml file and then simulate the pipeline but i’am getting an Error 500 code. so here’s my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:stable

stages:

Build image docker build: stage: Build image script:
- docker info
- docker build -t dockerregistry:1.0 .
```

if you need more information please tell me.

Got some logs for my Ci lint tests:

```
"POST /project_name/-/ci/lint HTTP/2.0" 500 2950 "https://gitlab.domain.com/project_name/-/ci/lint" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's having the same issue.
I fixed this by backing up only the repositories of our self signed gitlab and then Install gitlab on Docker with following the officiel Doc:
[enter link description here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html)

For the backup commands i used are like:

```
sudo gitlab-backup create SKIP=db,uploads,builds,artifacts,lfs,terraform_state,registry,pages,packages

uploads (attachments)
builds (CI job output logs)
artifacts (CI job artifacts)
lfs (LFS objects)
terraform_state (Terraform states)
registry (Container Registry images)
pages (Pages content)
packages (Packages)
```

After that, i installed Gitlab-ce with same version as the backup version then restore it following this command:

```
docker exec -it <name_container> gitlab-backup restore BACKUP=gitlab.tar.gz
```